# C++ : function pointer and class members

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have a problem with the following piece of code that can't even compile.
The problem is on the line

> class2_ = new Class2(myFunction);

In fact, I don't now how to reference myFunction, I have also tried  `class2_ = new Class2(&Class3::myFunction);` but the compiler still complains :(

2 constraints:

- The function myFunction can't be declared as static
- This code will be used in a Arduino base project, I can't use boost::bind

Could you please help me ?

Thanks.

```
class Class2 {
    typedef void(*MyFunction)  (int what);
    MyFunction fn_;
public:
    Class2(MyFunction fn) : fn_(fn) {}

    void invoke(int val) {
        fn_(val);
    }
};

class Class3 {
    Class2* class2_;
public:
    Class3() {
        class2_ = new Class2(myFunction);
        class2_->invoke(12);
    }

    void myFunction(int what) {
        // Do some work
    }
};

void test2() {
    Class3 instance3;
}
```

Comment: You can't supply a non-static member function where a non-member function is expected, this is because member functions have an implied "this" parameter which you would need to supply when calling the function.

Comment: your function is in a class always?

Comment: Are you able to use C++ 11?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [pointer to member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer).

```
class Class3;

class Class2 {
  typedef void(Class3::*MyFunction) (int);
  MyFunction fn_;
public:
  Class2(MyFunction fn) : fn_(fn) {}

  void invoke(Class3 *p, int val) {
    (p->*fn_)(val);
  }
};

class Class3 {
  Class2* class2_;
public:
  Class3() {
    class2_ = new Class2(&Class3::myFunction);
    class2_->invoke(this, 12);
  }

  void myFunction(int what) {
    // Do some work
  }
};
```

If you want that Class2 accepts any callable object with signature `void(int)`, then class template, function wrapper, lambda expression etc. will help.

Comment: Hi felix, many thanks for the tip, it works fine :) (as well as Daniel's solution)

Answer (score 0):

How about using an interface for that:

```
class ClassWithFunction {
public:
    virtual void myFunction(int what) = 0;
}


class Class2 {
    ClassWithFunction* fn_;
public:
    Class2(MyFunction* fn) : fn_(fn) {}

    void invoke(int val) {
        fn_->myFunction(val);
    }
};

class Class3 : ClassWithFunction {
    Class2* class2_;
public:
    Class3() {
        class2_ = new Class2(this);
        class2_->invoke(12);
    }

    void myFunction(int what) {
        // Do some work
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, many thanks for the tip, it works fine :) (as well as felix's solution)